# padding left with scroll-snap-align

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have created a carousel using scroll snap. Now I want to give padding left to the carousel container and when I swipe the items of carousel, they will overflow the padding area.

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
<div>
```

```
.grid {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-auto-columns: 100%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-left: 50px
}

.item {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    scroll-snap-stop: always;
}
```

I noticed that when I use scroll-snap-align: start css the padding left is not visible. How can I achieve padding left and also  scroll-snap-align: start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider applying [`scroll-padding-inline-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-padding-inline-start) or [`scroll-padding-left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-padding-left) to the scrolling container to create an offset for the `start` alignment of the scroll snapping. This visually emulates the padding:

```css
.grid {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 100%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  scroll-padding-inline-start: 50px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-left: 50px
}

.item {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```